# c# Entity Framework First Code как записать файл формата .doc/.docx

Tags: c#, entity-framework, framework, entity

Нужна база данных для хранения Word документов, подскажите какой формат поля нужен и как с ним работать.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что Вы хотите в базе хранить именно файлы? Другой организации данных не рассматриваете?

Comment: Неясно, какая у вас СУБД. SQL Server? какой версии? от этого зависят ответы.

Comment: blob или clob если верно понял суть вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class DocxEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] DocxFile { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DocxEntity> DocxFiles { get; set; }

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PutFileToDatabase("test.docx");
        GetFileFromDatabase(1, "out.docx");
    }

    static void PutFileToDatabase(string path)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            DocxEntity e = new DocxEntity();
            e.DocxFile = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(e.DocxFile, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            fs.Close();
            context.DocxFiles.Add(e);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    static void GetFileFromDatabase(int fileId, string path)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            DocxEntity e = context.DocxFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == fileId);
            if (e != null)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew);
                fs.Write(e.DocxFile, 0, e.DocxFile.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для этого тип `byte[]`, который автоматически отобразится на `varbinary(max)` в базе данных.

Также имеет смысл включить для этой колонки FILESTREAM, но для этого придется "ковыряться" в БД напрямую.